# AngularJS name availability

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive to check username availability. But no matter the return result from server, the form still disabled the submit button.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

});
    myApp.directive('verifyStore', function($timeout, $q, $http) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
          model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() { 
            //here you should access the backend, to check if username exists
            //and return a promise
             return $http.get('/api/verifystore').then(function(res){
              $timeout(function(){
                model.$setValidity('usernameExists', true); ---> or false button still disabled
              }, 1000);
            }); 
          };

        }
      } 
    });

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" verify-store ng-model="storename" class="form-control" name="merchant.store_name" placeholder="Store Name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required>
        <div ng-if="signupForm.$pending.usernameExists">checking....</div>
        <div ng-if="signupForm.$error.usernameExists">username exists already</div>
        </div>
```

The Submit button

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                            Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </button>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your promise needs to reject when the username exists.

```
     model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() { 
         return $http.get('/api/verifystore').then(function(res){
             return res ? $q.reject('that username exists') : res;
         }); 
      };
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators

Answer (score 0):

In case the username is accepted by your server you have to resolve the promise.
You can do this by just returning `true`.
In case the username already exists you have to reject the promise, as TKrugg already mentioned.

Have a look at this little [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RTG5kb8t9aus2u5Let91). Instead of using $timeout service just do your server call.

```
app.directive('verifyStore', function($timeout, $q, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
            model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                //here you should access the backend, to check if username exists
                //and return a promise
                return $http.get([yourUrl]).then(function(response) {
                    if (!response.data.validUsername) {
                        return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```